# Как найти id темы в группах telegram и отправить сообщение python?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

У меня есть группа (бесседа), в ней есть разделы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне надо научится отправлять конкретным темам сообщения с помощи бота. Я использую библиотеку `pyTelegramBotAPI`. Возможно ли это сделать?